# minimum number of non-terminals so that for all context-sensitive languages there is a non-contracting grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

Every context-sensitive language $\subseteq \Sigma^* = \{a,b\}^*$ can be expressed using an essentially non-contracting grammar.
With just one non-terminal symbol, we can't express all context-sensitive languages.

Does there exist a minimum $k$, such that all context-sensitive languages can be expressed as a non-contracting grammar with $k$ non-terminal symbols?